# モデルのメソッドでのself.saveについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ログ関連のDBに保存するためにActive Recordのモデルでデータの保存をできないかと考えています。

以下のようなものを考えているのですが、クラスメソッドで新規のモデルを作成するのも変なようですし、インスタンスメソッドでも「self.save」のような動作ができないので自身のモデルの中で新規作成ができないか質問させていただきました。

```
def log_save(msg)
  self.msg = msg
  self.save
end
```

そもそもの考え方的に自身のモデルの中で保存しないものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> クラスメソッドで新規のモデルを作成するのも変なよう

そんなことはないです。`Model.create`はクラスメソッドです。

例えばJSON文字列を元にレコードを作りたいのであれば以下のようなメソッドを定義する方法が考えられます。

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_from_json(json)
    param = JSON.parse(json)
    # その他 param をごにょごにょする
    self.create(param)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

質問の背景が上手く読み取れないのですが、別のLogクラスを用意するのではダメなのでしょうか？

```
class MyData
  def log_save(msg)
    MyDateLog.create(my_data: self, msg: msg)
  end
end

class MyDataLog
  has_one :my_data
end
```